# Why do I get odd behaviour with my JavaScript files in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've got 3 the following JS files for my controllers:

```
movie.js.coffeee
application.js
facebook.js.coffee.erb
sessions.js.coffee
users.js.coffee
```

For some reason, when I put JS code in my users.js.coffee, or facebook.js.coffee.erb (or any other file for that matter) in a $(document).ready, it doesn't fire. i.e. I put a simple alert in users.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  alert 'hello'
```

But this doesn't execute.

I've also got code to utilise Facebook's JavaScript SDK in facebook.js.coffee.erb but that all doesn't execute when I place code within $(document).ready().

I've had to resort to put all my JS code within the movie.js.coffee file and it all works in there. Within that file I've got the following code:

```
$ ->

    #Home page login dropdown
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()

    $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click (e) ->
        e.stopPropagation()

    #Users edit page
    $('.hint a').tooltip()

    #Movie show page
    $('#movie-tabs a:first').tab('show')

    $('#movie-info').stickyMojo({footerID: '#footer', contentID: '#movie-description'})
```

My application.js file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

This is quite annoying, any idea why this may be happening? When the JS code is not wrapped in a $(document).ready in other files, it works, but I'd ideally like to avoid this.

Comment: I usually just manually include the js file in my manifest and it works. The `require_tree .` doesn't seem to work that well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ->
  'alert hello'
```

You've just put a string there, not a call to `alert`, so this won't do anything.

```
$ ->
  alert('hello')
```

That should work.

Comment: No I just made this mistake when copying the code over. I didn't actually do this. So the code I used was the same as you just gave but it still doesn't fire.

Comment: Are the files actually being loaded in the HTML? i.e. if you check the HTML, do the files appear there? Do you get any console (firebug, etc.) errors? There are a lot of things you can do to narrow down the source of the problem. First step is to figure out if this is a sprockets problem or a javascript problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this sort of problem a while ago. I can't tell why it happens, but I deleted the coffee files and created them again and it worked. Check your indentation, too, since CoffeeScript's syntax is based on it.

Also, you should use `jQuery ->` instead of `$ ->` so it won't get confused if there's any other JS framework you might use in the same project.

Comment: Did you have your files as file.js.coffee or file.coffee?

Comment: It probably was file.js.coffee because I hadn't changed them. Try creating a sandbox Rails app just to check if it happens again.